# Remove Attribute-defined `onload` from `<body>`

Tags: javascript, html, events

I've been working on this for a few hours and am at the point where I feel like I might be trying to accomplish something unworkable. Any advice or insight is definitely appreciated!

The use case I'm targeting requires interrupting the browser's DOM parsing before it has a chance to draw the `<body>` element. To accomplish this, I've used this one-liner as the first script called in my `<head>` element:

```js
document.replaceChild(document.createElement('html'), document.children[0]);
```

This successfully prevents the browser from calling any subsequent scripts, and the `<body>` element remains un-rendered. However, if the markup includes an `onload` attribute on the `<body>` element, that function or code is still called by the browser.

As the context which intercepts DOM parsing is in `<head>`, I can't use `document.body.removeEventListener()` to drop the event listener, because the `body` element doesn't exist yet. Setting `window.onload` to `null` has no effect, and neither does trying to intercept setting of `window.onload` using `Object.defineProperty(window, 'onload', {...})`. In each case, the `onload` function or statements still get called.

To preempt the obvious question as to why I can't just avoid using `<body onload="...">`, the use case is for developer tooling, so I'm trying to create contingency for certain absolute conditions. If it can't be done, it isn't killer to my project, but I'd sure like to know *why* it can't be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's brilliant. The following seems to do the trick quite nicely: `document.onreadystatechange = () => {if (document.readyState === 'interactive') window.onload = null;}` Thank you so much! If you promote your comment to an answer, I'll select it as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Document readystate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) at the `interactive` state, and overwrite the `onload` attribute.

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
   if (document.readyState === 'interactive') 
      window.onload = null;
}
```

(Added your code from your comment for completeness.)